# How to display the x,y coordinates of some reference values

Tags: matlab

I have some values that I have randomly generated and ascribed to some x, y coordinates. However, I will like to extract the coordinates (x, y) of the three highest values and display them as a 3 by 2 matrix.

```
x = [1 1 10 10];
y = [1 10 1 10];

rand_val (1,:) = [randi([5,10],1),randi([5,10],1),randi([5,10],1),randi([5,10],1)];
z = rand_val
out = zeros(10);
out(sub2ind(size(out),x,y)) = z
```

Comment: You could replace the 3rd and 4th line with `z=randi([5,10],1,4)`, not solving your question but definitely simplifying the code.

Comment: It's not really clear how your example is related to the question asked. The three highest values of *what*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort in descending order, then get the position for the three largest elements, then convert the linear indices to subscript indices:

```
[~,ix]=sort(out(:),'descend')
[x2,y2]=ind2sub(size(out),ix(1:3))
```